# Python selenium:::

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list;

```
days = ['day20', 'day2', 'day3', 'day4', 'day5', 'day6', 'day7', 'day8', 'day9', 'day10', 'day11', 'day12', 'day13', 'day14', 'day15', 'day16', 'day17', 'day18', 'day19', 'day20', 'day21', 'day22', 'day23', 'day24', 'day25', 'day26', 'day27', 'day28', 'day29', 'day30']
```

I need to call the various days in a for loop code below;

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('gtframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
for day in days:
    driver.find_element_by_id("day").click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
    "//iframe[@title='fname1']")))
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Frats Gashe']"))
    time.sleep(5)
```

How do I achieve this??

Comment: You're already calling days in for loop. Please be clear on what do you want

Comment: You're using the literal string value `"day"` instead of the variable `day`.  Take out the quotes.